# Can we replicate ACF functionality in our theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

Hi i want to add advance custom fields in my wordpress theme. I don't need editor functionality but to provide the users the facility to enter the values to view in the frontend.

basically i want to add the custom fields in my theme just like ACF but i don't want to use the plugin. Is there anything anyone can help me out with this please do.

I'm using ACF plugin right now to add custom fields in my theme.

For example I'm getting the designation from user in the admin panel and our team members custom post type. and showing it on the home page by using this code.

```
<p><span class="fa fa-user-circle"></span> Designation</strong>:<?php echo the_field( 'designation' ); ?> </p>
```

I don't want to use ACF plugin to perform this task. I know about the wordpress custom field. The problem with wordpress custom field is I've to select the key every time when I create a post. Here's a sample of  what I'm trying to do. I want to add the this in my add new post. [image]

Right now I've to select the key value whenever a new post is created. I want something similar to the image attached in my add new post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native WordPress function(s) to do the same thing. Of course, you lose the extensive ACF features and slick ACF admin panels.

Instead of using ACF's `get_field()`, you can use `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'field', true);`

List all items in the meta field 'appartments' like so:

```
$meta_name = 'appartments';
$fields = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_name, true ); 
foreach ( $fields as $fieldValue )
{ 
   echo $fieldValue . ' ';
}
```

Comment: but the issue with this is I don't want to select the value everytime when i add a new post. This can do the trick but I've to select the key every time.

Comment: Are you saying you want an alternative to `get_field()` without ACF plugin?

Comment: I'm saying I want to add custom fields in my posts so that i don't have to select the key everytime i create a new post. I want a simple permanent solution for this.